# Check the string length and append a charecter to make it to a constant length

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<Data>
<AA>123</AA>
  <AA>45658</AA>
  <AA>123456789</AA> 
</Data>
```

Output needed:

```
<info>
  <Numbers id="000000123" />
  <Numbers id="000045658" />
  <Numbers id="123456789" />
</info>
```

Condition:

I need to check for the string length of value of the element AA. If the length is less than 9 I need to append '0' s to make it 9 digit in length.

XSLT wrote:

```
<xsl:template match="Data">   
  <info>
       <xsl:for-each select="AA">
              <Numbers>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                  <xsl:variable name="numlenght">
                  <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$numlenght&lt;9">
                      <xsl:variable name="balance">
                        <xsl:value-of select="9-$numlenght"/>
                      </xsl:variable>
                      <xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;$balance]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
                      </xsl:for-each>

                    </xsl:when>
                                      </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>

                </xsl:attribute>
              </Numbers>
            </xsl:for-each>
  </info>
        </xsl:template>
```

I am not getting the exact output.

Can any one suggest how to do that?

Comment: Just a quick note - you have misspelt "length" a number of times throughout the code you have provided.

Comment: @Lucanos, this is where being a dyslexic in programming isn't a problem - as long as you **always** spell the variable incorrectly the same way each time, it doesn't matter ;-)

Comment: @freefaller, agreed. But it does tend to be an indicator of a programmer who is more likely to experience "bugs" due to simple instances of poor syntax or incorrectly named variables. That and trying to call standard functions/properties when you misspell them will _always_ cause trouble. (For instance, in javascript, `array.lenght` is never going to fly, unless you have declared your own custom property with the misspelt name.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This requires less memory**:

```
concat(substring('000000000', string-length() +1), .)
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <info><xsl:apply-templates/></info>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="AA">
  <Numbers id="{concat(substring('000000000', string-length() +1), .)}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
    <AA>123</AA>
    <AA>45658</AA>
    <AA>123456789</AA>
</Data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<info>
   <Numbers id="000000123"/>
   <Numbers id="000045658"/>
   <Numbers id="123456789"/>
</info>
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
concat(substring('000000000', string-length() +1), .)
```

**doesn't construct a string with length greater than 9** (as in another answer, that after this extracts a substring of the longer than 9 characters string).

In contrast, it extracts only the necessary for padding number of `0` characters and then concatenates them to the current node's string value.

**Do note**:

**This**:

```
  <Numbers id="{concat(substring('000000000', string-length() +1), .)}"/>
```

**can be simplified further to this**:

```
  <Numbers id="{substring('000000000', string-length() +1)}{.}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Concat and substring to make it something like this:

```
susbstring(concat('000000000',yourstring),string-length()-9,9)
```

Comment: @amters. Thank you for the answer. I am getting all '0' in the output.

Comment: The output I got is <info>
  <Numbers id="00" />
  <Numbers id="0000" />
  <Numbers id="00000000" />
</info>

Comment: @User, based on this answer try `substring(concat('000000000',yourstring),string-length()+1)`. (Note the `+1` instead of `-9,9`)